# 4 modes of convergence and regular "lim"?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I've learned about 4 modes of convergence for random variables, convergence in probability, almost sure, in $L^P$, and in distribution.

How do these modes compare to the regular "limit"? Is "limit" one of these 4? If so, which one? Or is it something else?

Take for example the dominated convergence theorem. It requires $X_n \rightarrow X$ and $X_n \le Y$ for some integrable $Y$, and then it lets us say $E X_n \rightarrow E X$. But what sort of convergence is implied in $X_n \rightarrow X$? Almost sure? In probability? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: In $X_n\to X$ it is almost sure. It is the $\lim$ as you know it for functions. Actually, it is $X_n(ω)\to X(ω)$ for almost all $ω\in Ω$. Now $EX_n$ and $EX$ are numbers, so they live in $\mathbb R$ and here the $\lim$ is the $\lim$ as you know it for sequences. The limit is always the same thing

Comment: They are all limits in different topologies.